# Dynamic column names for subsetting

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to subset a dataframe based on a dynamic name.

My hardcoded version looks like this...

```
persona_subset <- subset(newList, subset = (finalList$flag_analoggers =='1'))
```

I would like to be able to create a list of variables and iterate through the list, substituting a different column name each time. For example...

```
//Run 1
persona_subset <- subset(newList, subset = (finalList$flag_1 =='1'))
//Run 2
persona_subset <- subset(newList, subset = (finalList$flag_2 =='1'))
//Run n...
persona_subset <- subset(newList, subset = (finalList$flag_n =='1'))
```

However, everytime I put the variable in there, I get the 'Subset must be logical' error. I tried putting the variable name into a string, but am not getting the correct subset of the data.

```
col_location <- paste("finalList$",toString(x))
persona_subset <- subset(newList, subset = (col_location =='1'))
```

How can I dynamically iterate through this variable list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were in your place, I would avoid `subset`, and manage the issue like this.

```
xy <- data.frame(vals1 = runif(9), vals2 = runif(9), a = sample(1:3, 9, replace = TRUE), 
                 b = sample(1:3, 9, replace = TRUE), c = sample(1:3, 9, replace = TRUE), 
                 d = sample(1:3, 9, replace = TRUE))

iterate.vals <- names(xy)[!grepl("vals", names(xy))]
sapply(iterate.vals, FUN = function(x) {
  print(xy[xy[, x] == 1, ])
  # Run
})

      vals1     vals2 a b c d
2 0.6165867 0.3728094 1 1 2 1
3 0.2962395 0.9669952 1 3 1 2
7 0.5657228 0.7200541 1 3 2 3
8 0.7793529 0.8391430 1 1 1 1
      vals1     vals2 a b c d
1 0.6028678 0.9178560 2 1 1 3
2 0.6165867 0.3728094 1 1 2 1
5 0.7234325 0.8426445 2 1 1 1
6 0.5637070 0.1895586 2 1 2 3
8 0.7793529 0.8391430 1 1 1 1
      vals1     vals2 a b c d
1 0.6028678 0.9178560 2 1 1 3
3 0.2962395 0.9669952 1 3 1 2
4 0.9293780 0.3459115 2 2 1 3
5 0.7234325 0.8426445 2 1 1 1
8 0.7793529 0.8391430 1 1 1 1
      vals1     vals2 a b c d
2 0.6165867 0.3728094 1 1 2 1
5 0.7234325 0.8426445 2 1 1 1
8 0.7793529 0.8391430 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Much better. `bquote` was a pain with that underscore